Kubernetes Dashboard with OAuth2 Proxy returns 401 after successful Azure AD login
I've been struggling with an authentication issue in my Kubernetes Dashboard setup. While the OAuth2 Proxy successfully authenticates with Azure AD and sets the correct cookies (_oauth2_proxy), the dashboard keeps rejecting the authorization.
Environment

Kubernetes Dashboard (Helm chart version 7.10.0)
OAuth2 Proxy (Helm chart version 7.7.28)
Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)
Nginx Ingress Controller
Cert-Manager for TLS
Dashboard served under subpath /k8s-dashboard

Setup
Kubernetes Dashboard Configuration
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: dashboard-admin
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  labels:
    app: kubernetes-dashboard
automountServiceAccountToken: true

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: dashboard-admin-token
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: dashboard-admin
  labels:
    app: kubernetes-dashboard
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: dashboard-admin
  labels:
    app: kubernetes-dashboard
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: dashboard-admin
    namespace: kubernetes-dashboard

---
apiVersion: helm.cattle.io/v1
kind: HelmChart
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  repo: https://kubernetes.github.io/dashboard/
  chart: kubernetes-dashboard
  version: 7.10.0
  targetNamespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  valuesContent: |-
    app:
      labels:
        app: kubernetes-dashboard
      ingress:
        enabled: true
        ingressClassName: nginx
        path: /k8s-dashboard
        hosts:
          - my-cluster.region.cloudapp.azure.com
        annotations:
          nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: 64k
          nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
          nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: true
          nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: true
          nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://$host/oauth2/auth
          nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri
          nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: Authorization,X-Auth-Request-User,X-Auth-Request-Email
        issuer:
          name: letsencrypt-prod
          scope: cluster
        tls:
          enabled: true
          secretName: tls-dashboard

---
apiVersion: helm.cattle.io/v1
kind: HelmChart
metadata:
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  repo: https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/manifests
  chart: oauth2-proxy
  version: 7.7.28
  targetNamespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  valuesContent: |-
    ingress:
      enabled: true
      className: nginx
      path: /oauth2
      hosts:
        - my-cluster.region.cloudapp.azure.com
      tls:
        - secretName: tls-oauth-dashboard
          hosts:
            - my-cluster.region.cloudapp.azure.com
      annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: 64k
    
    config:
      clientID: "your-client-id"
      clientSecret: "your-client-secret"
      cookieSecret: "your-cookie-secret"
      configFile: |
        provider = "azure"
        email_domains = ["*"]
        azure_tenant = "your-tenant-id"
        oidc_issuer_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-tenant-id/v2.0"
        validate_url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
        
        # Upstream configuration
        upstreams = ["file:///dev/null"]
        
        # Cookie settings
        cookie_secure = true
        cookie_domains = ["my-cluster.region.cloudapp.azure.com"]
        
        # Azure AD specific settings
        scope = "openid email profile"
        
        # Request handling
        skip_provider_button = true
        set_authorization_header = true
        set_xauthrequest = true
        
        # SSL/TLS settings
        ssl_insecure_skip_verify = true
        ssl_upstream_insecure_skip_verify = true
        
        # Auth endpoints
        whitelist_domains = ["my-cluster.region.cloudapp.azure.com"]
        redirect_url = "https://my-cluster.region.cloudapp.azure.com/oauth2/callback"
        skip_auth_routes = ["/oauth2/callback$"]

Issue

I can successfully log in through Azure AD
The OAuth2 Proxy correctly sets the _oauth2_proxy cookie
After login, I'm correctly redirected back to the dashboard
However, when the dashboard makes a request to the /me endpoint, it receives a 401 Unauthorized error:

{
    "ErrStatus": {
        "metadata": {},
        "status": "Failure",
        "message": "MSG_LOGIN_UNAUTHORIZED_ERROR",
        "reason": "Unauthorized",
        "code": 401
    }
}


The dashboard then shows the token input page
Even when generating a new token using kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard create token dashboard-admin and inputting it, the dashboard still returns 401

Does anyone know why this might be happening?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

What I had to do to get mine to work was make sure that upn was added to my tokens in the app registration. Here's my working config for Azure Helm values.yaml files
Kubernetes dashboard
app:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    ingressClassName: nginx
    path: /k8s-dashboard
    hosts:
    - kubernetes-dashboard-test.cookes.io
    annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: 64k
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://$host/oauth2/auth
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: Authorization,X-Auth-Request-User,X-Auth-Request-Email
  settings:
    global:
      clusterName: kube-test
      itemsPerPage: 50
      labelsLimit: 10
auth:
  scaling:
    replicas: 1
api:
  scaling:
    replicas: 1
web:
  scaling:
    replicas: 1
metricsScraper:
  scaling:
    replicas: 1
metrics-server:
  enabled: true

oauth2-proxy
config:
  clientID: <azure client id>
  clientSecret: <azure client secret
  cookieSecret: <some random data>
  cookieName: oauth2-proxy
  configFile: |-
    provider = "azure"
    email_domains = [ "*" ]
    azure_tenant = <azure tenant id>
    upstreams = [ "file:///dev/null" ]
    cookie_secure = true
    cookie_domains = ["<dashboard fqdn>"]
    scope = "openid email profile"
    #skip_provider_button = true
    set_authorization_header = true
    set_xauthrequest = true
    ssl_upstream_insecure_skip_verify = true
    whitelist_domains = [ "*." ]
    skip_auth_routes = ["/oauth2/callback$"]

    pass_access_token = true
    pass_authorization_header = true

ingress:
  enabled: true
  className: nginx
  hosts:
  - kubernetes-dashboard-test.cookes.io
extraArgs:
- --provider-display-name=Azure
- --oidc-issuer-url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<azure tenant id>/v2.0
- --ssl-insecure-skip-verify=true
- --pass-access-token=true

Here's my app registration api permissions

Here's my app registration token configuration


Thank you for taking the time to answer. I'll test it and let you know if it works. Btw, do we need the extraArgs in the oauth2 proxy? I think we can put everything under config file right?
